# What is the commonly used "DS" of ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to ember.js, I've just started reading the tutorials and playing with it and I find something which is not very clear and I couldn't google for a proper explanation: in the modeling section, they use an object named "DS" (http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/modeling-data/)
can you tell me what this object is and where it's defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DS` is the namespace for ember-data, and is available when you also import [ember-data](http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js) in your project.

Hope it helps.